# How to make Git forget a file after delete

Tags: git, merge, branch, delete-file, conflict

I have two Branches X and Y that use to contain the same file "sample.txt". I want this file only in Branch Y and therefore, deleted in Branch X and did a HEAD commit.

Now, whenever I merge the branch Y to X, it show conflict with "sample.txt" [deleted/modified]. I would like to make GIT forget that there was any file "sample.txt" in Branch X, so that while merging it never reads the same file from Branch Y and show a conflict.

Comment: Unfortunately git doesn't allow you to easily do this. May I ask what is the purpose of this file if it should only live in one branch?

Comment: The [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) command will let you permanently remove a file from your git history.

Comment: @larsks IMO, this is not a use case for `git filter-repo`. Branch Y is supposed to contain the file, therefore completely removing the file from the repository is not a solution. Filtering only one branch would result in problems when merging (there would either be no merge base because of completely divergent histories, or the merge base would be the commit before the file was introduced in branch X – this would result in the merge re-adding the file to branch X).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you for your response. We have different environment-specific files: dev.sql / tst.sql / acc.sql / prd.sql. And I want dev.sql in DEV branch and so on. So, I have deleted tst.sql and others from DEV branch. Now, if i back merge TST into DEV (after changes tst.sql in TST) then DEV shows [deleted/modified] conflict everytime. I tried .gitattributes but it works only with available files and not with deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

["You can't get there from here."](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/you+can%27t+get+there+from+here.html)  [(Boston variant.)](http://andywoodruff.com/blog/you-cant-get-there-from-here/) You'll just have to remember to use care when merging.  Well, sometimes.  Sometimes you'll get a conflict!  Here's *when and why*.  Note that when you *do* get a conflict, you still have to use care.  That's the true general answer: **When merging in Git, use care.**  Git is a tool (or set of tools), not a solution.

Once you've done the merge correctly once, you will probably *not* have to do it carefully by hand again.  But always use care when merging!

#### Branches don't matter

In Git, only *commits* matter.  Commits are permanent (mostly) and unchangeable (entirely) and *are* the history in the repository.  *Branch names* simply select one particular commit.

#### Commits exist on multiple branches simultaneously

Let's take a look at a simple case of branching in Git.  Here, we start with a tiny repository, with three commits in it.  Commit `A`—whose real hash ID is some random-looking number, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)—is the very first commit.  Commit `B`, the second commit, refers directly to (in fact, literally contains) commit `A`'s hash ID.  We say that commit `B` *points to* commit `A`.  Commit `C`, the third and currently last commit, refers to commit `B`'s hash ID.  Hence we have:

```
A <-B <-C
```

In order to locate commit `C`—whose hash ID is, remember, random-looking: there's no way to know *a priori* that commit `C` is the last one without reading all the commits and working it out, and in a large repository this would be undesirably slow, for instance—Git stores commit `C`'s hash ID in a *branch name*.  This allows Git to find commit `C` very quickly.  Let's use the name `main`, as GitHub do now, to store this hash ID:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

(The commits themselves *always* point backwards.  They must, because we don't know what `B`'s hash ID will be when we create `A`, nor what `C`'s will be when we create `B`.  But for drawing purposes on StackOverflow I normally resort to connecting lines, as the arrow fonts don't work very well on some systems.)

To make a new commit on `main`, we select that branch name, which selects that commit.  This also copies the files—commits store full snapshots, with each commit having a full copy of every file as of the time you, or whoever, made the commit—out so that you can see them and work on them.  We make some changes and make a new commit, which gets a new, unique, random-looking (but not actually random) hash ID that we'll call `D`.  Git:

- makes sure `D` contains the right snapshot (from Git's *staging area*);
- uses your name and email address, as of their configuration right now, as the author and committer of this new commit;
- uses "now" (date-and-time) as the time-stamps for this new commit;
- gathers a log message to include in the commit;
- uses the *current commit's hash ID* `C` as the parent hash ID for the new commit, so that new commit `D` will *point to* `C`; and
- writes all of this out, obtaining the actual hash ID for new commit `D`:

  A--B--C   <-- main

  D

Now comes the magic step: Git simply stores the *new* commit's hash ID into whichever *branch name* we are using *right now*.  This causes the *name* `main` to point to new commit `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main
```

If we now create several new branches:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main, topic1, topic2
```

*all three names* will select the *same* commit `D`.  We pick one of the three names to be the "current branch", and draw this by attaching the special name `HEAD`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main, topic1 (HEAD), topic2
```

Making several new commits, one at a time, causes only the *current branch name* to advance:

```
           E--F   <-- topic1 (HEAD)
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- main, topic2
```

If we now `git checkout topic2`, Git *removes* all the files that go with commit `F`—the one we had out a moment ago—and *installs in their place* all the files that go with commit `D`:

```
           E--F   <-- topic1
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- main, topic2 (HEAD)
```

Making two new commits now produces:

```
           E--F   <-- topic1
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- main
          \
           G--H   <-- topic2 (HEAD)
```

Now, here's the weird and special thing about Git: commits `A-B-C-D` are in fact on *all three branches*.  We're allowed to *delete* the name `main` entirely now:

```
           E--F   <-- topic1
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           G--H   <-- topic2 (HEAD)
```

#### Merging

If we merge the two topics, we get a *merge commit*, which is a commit that points back to two or more parents.  Git constructs the *snapshot* for this commit on its own.  To do so, Git works backwards from the two *branch tip* commits, here `F` and `H`, to find the *best common (shared) commit*.  In this case, that's commit `D`.

Git then figures out what has *changed* since the snapshot in `D` in each of the two branch-tip snapshots.  These are the *changes to be combined*.  If one of the changes is *delete a file*, and the other is *do nothing to the file*, the combination of these two is *delete that file*.

If one change is *delete a file* and the other is *modify the file* ... well, *that*, to Git, is a conflict.  It can't both make one small change to the file *and* delete the file entirely.  So this time you would get a conflict.

Nothing else matters but what has happened to each file since the merge base.  So the crucial questions are:

- Which commit is the merge base?
- What happened to each file, since then, to get to the two branch-tip commits?

In any case, Git may construct the merge result entirely on its own, or it may stop with a conflict—depending on what happened to each file—and make you fix things up.  Either way, you will eventually arrive at the final set of files and contents that should go into a *new* commit.  If you have to fix up a merge mess manually, you store these files into Git's *staging area* just as for a regular non-merge commit.<sup>1</sup>  Then you finish the merge and Git makes a merge commit

Here, I'll assume we ran `git checkout topic1; git merge topic2` and it just worked:

```
           E--F
          /    \
A--B--C--D      I   <-- topic1 (HEAD)
          \    /
           G--H   <-- topic2
```

Note how the *name* `topic1` is the one that got updated.  The name `topic2` still points to existing commit `H`.  But we can now safely delete that *name*, if we're done using it; once we do, we just have the name `topic1`.  *All* commits are now on `topic1`, because moving backwards from `I` to both `F` *and* `H` means that all commits are *reachable from* the merge commit.  (For much more on the concept of *reachability*, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).)

We can now rename `topic1` to `main` if we like:

```
           E--F
          /    \
A--B--C--D      I   <-- main (HEAD)
          \    /
           G--H
```

and now all commits are on just one branch, named `main`.  The branch names never really mattered at all, except to *find* the commits.  Each name *selects* one particular commit—by pointing to it—and that commit is, by definition, the *last* commit that is on that branch.  All earlier commits that are *reachable from* that point are also on that branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that the *staging area*, which Git also calls the *index* and—rarely these days—the *cache*, is separate from your *working tree*, where you have files that you can see and work on.  The existence of this staging area is why you have to run `git add` so often, for instance.

There are version control systems that don't have a staging area.  They still need something at least vaguely similar, but they *hide* it and don't make *you* work through it.  But Git is not one of these: Git is loud-and-proud about its staging area, and forces you to learn about it.  Don't try to get by without learning about it.

---

#### Merging changes future merge bases

The most important point of all here is not just learning how the merge works, by finding a merge base, but learning that a *future* merge may use a *different merge base*.  Let's draw a more complicated situation, with a main branch and an on-going development branch that gets merged repeatedly:

```
...--o--B1-o--L---M1--o---M2--o   <-- main
         \       /       /
          o--o--B2--o--B2--o--o   <-- develop
```

Here, `B1` was the merge base at some point.  In particular, it was the merge base at *this* point:

```
...--o--B1-o--L   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          o--o--B2   <-- develop
```

We were on `main` as `HEAD` and ran `git merge develop` and Git *found* `B1` as the merge base.  Git compared the snapshot in `B1` to the snapshot in `L` to see what we changed on `main`, and compared the snapshot in `B1` to the snapshot in `B2` to see what they (whoever they are) changed on `develop`.  Git then *combined these changes* and made new merge commit `M1`:

```
...--o--B1-o--L---M1   <-- main (HEAD)
         \       /
          o--o--B2   <-- develop
```

Later, after more development commits and another commit on `main`, we had this situation:

```
...--o--B1-o--L---M1--o   <-- main
         \       /
          o--o--B2--o--B2   <-- develop
```

We run `git checkout main` and `git merge develop`.  Git searches backwards from the latest (rightmost `o`) commit on `main`, and searches backwards from the latest (`B2`) commit on `develop`.  Going backwards from `main` finds boring commit `o`, then commit `M1`, then commits `L` and `B2` at the same time.  Going backwards from `develop` finds `B2`, boring commit `o` (different from the one on `main`), and then commit `B2`.

**Commit `B2` is on both branches** so it is a candidate for being the merge base.  Furthermore, it's the *best* such candidate, so it is in fact the merge base.

This means that when Git is doing the merge this time, it's the comparison against the shared `B2` commit that matters!  Suppose you have a file that was in `B1`, was deleted before `B2`, but *does* appear in `M1`, or at least in the subsequent `o` commit (perhaps you *added the file back* **after** Git deleted it via an unconflicted merge; that's one of your options when being careful).  Suppose further that the absent-from-`B1` file is still absent from `B2`.  Then the comparison results include:

```
B1 vs o-on-main => add file
B1 vs B2 => do nothing at all
```

The *combination* of these two changes, in Git's merging rules, is *add the file*.  So Git's automatic `M2` merge results will *keep the file* in the form that it has in what's currently the last commit on `main`.

Once that merge is done—commit `M2` exists—commit `B2` will be the future merge base for:

```
...--o--B1-o--L---M1--o---M2   <-- main
         \       /       /
          o--o--B2--o--B2--o   <-- develop
```

for instance, because `B2` is on *both branches* (via `M2`).